# Don't put a check mark near "ask a question or contribute an answer" on the list of privileges for suspended users

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, account-suspension, privileges-page

A suspended user sees the following on [/help/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

[image: Check mark near "Create posts"]

I find the [image: check mark] next to "create posts" misleading since suspended users cannot create posts.

Comment: The text for "create posts" seems to be faded out.  Is this perhaps a sign that the user has that privilege blocked?

Answer (score 3):

No, if we do this, we'll have to:

- Remove the checkmark on "flag posts" if you're banned from flagging
- During chatbans, remove the checkmark on "talk in chat"
- If you're review banned, remove the checkmark on "access review queues"

And possibly others.

This conflicts with the fundamental purpose of the checkmark: it indicates that you *have* the privilege, and even if you're blocked from it, you still have it.  This would also confuse users ("why don't I have 'flag posts' yet" or "I have the 'set bounties' privilege but not 'talk in chat'").

Comment: How about keeping checkmark but adding some warning?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Good idea, but you should probably post a separate question about that.

Comment: sounds good, will do

Comment: Talk in chat is.. weird. If your parent site is different from the site you are suspended on, you can still chat.

Comment: If this is so, then you should still have the check marks of the privileges you would have had had you not been suspended.

Comment: How about a red `⊖` icon (circled minus) instead of the checkmark?

Comment: Done: [Add a warning near the “ask a question or contribute an answer” on the list of privileges for suspended users indicating the privilege is suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363671/178179)